# Margin ( or padding not sure ) problem in Chrome/Safari

Tags: css, safari, google-chrome

Heres my link ( BE WARNED, its got autoplay audio - sorry...!)

[link text](http://tinyurl.com/bt5n4c)

Its not the usual 'looks fine in FF but bad in IE' problem :)

It looks fine in IE6/7 Firefox, but in Chrome & Safari it has big problems with what looks like either margin/padding, or positioning. ( That narrows it down eh? )

If you have a look you'll see what I mean. It looks like I may have a conflict with one of my CSS rules, but then wouldn't that cause problems consistently across all browsers?

Any help and pointers is gratefully received. Thank you.

EDIT:Unsure as to why my reset.css rules are not taking effect...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the margin-top on the `<h4>` inside `product-panel-content` `<div>`s.

Modify the following style in `site.css`:

```
.product-panel-content h4 {
    font-size:140%;
    letter-spacing:-0.5px;
}
```

to be:

```
.product-panel-content h4 {
    font-size:140%;
    margin-top:0;
    letter-spacing:-0.5px;
}
```

Will fix the display issue in WebKit-based browsers (Safari and Chrome, for example). I am not sure if this will cause other display issues for your other browsers but experiment with using `padding-top` on the `<h4>` to supplement the lack of margin for spacing on that element if it does.

Comment: Many thanks bjeanes, there are a lot more similar problems like this on the page. I'm curious as to why my reset.css rules don't appear to take care of them..

Comment: cos I didn't use the universal selector, *{margin:0;paddding:0}, DOH

Answer (score -1):

The difference between Chrome and any other browser is that it takes specified width for an element and *adds* the padding to get the final width.   whereas other browsers use padding to space inner content in and keep the specified width for the element.   Chrome fell off the boat on that one.

Comment: Actually, that's how the W3C box-model was specified, and all browsers do that now, including IE, unless you force them into quirks mode.